# Not getting appropriate Latitude Longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am a iOS application developer. I am working with Location Manager.

For every 5 seconds I am capturing the latitude and longitude and storing the CLLocation object in array. The lat and long is not completely correct when I am trying to draw those location in Map.

My code is following below:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{//ios6&+
CLLocation *loc;
NSInteger objCount = [locations count];
if (objCount >= 1) {
    loc = [locations objectAtIndex:objCount - 1];

    NSArray *Arr_TotalTime = [Str_TotalTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

            [ArrayOfLocations addObject:loc];
    }
}
```

Any one can please give me more info to get ACTUAL location (lat, long) from didupdatelocation method.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting the actual location. A CLLocation contains a coordinate which contains a latitude and longtitude value which are right. You may be interpreting the value incorrectly when you're trying to render it on a map (you're not saying what map app you're using or what API). A typical error is using the fractional part of the lat/long as a minutes/seconds value (which it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set up your location manager, the accuracy will vary.
Try something like this:

#### Location Manager

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];    
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
```

#### Method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSDate *eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if ((abs(howRecent) <= 5) && (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0) && (newLocation.verticalAccuracy > 0) && (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 100) && (newLocation.verticalAccuracy < 100)) 
    {
        [ArrayOfLocations addObject:newLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        // received bad signal
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreLocation to get the longitude and latitude.

Include framework:

Click your project in navigator.

Click the plus button under "link binary with libraries"

Add Corelocation to your project.

Import the header file:

## import

Declare CLLocationManager:

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
initialize locationManager:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then, use

float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;